# Performance test with Taurus

Tags: performance-testing, taurus

I am new to performance testing and would like to know what the following output from [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org) means (http://websi.te is NOT the real domain name of my test!):

```
10:53:12 INFO: Test duration: 0:06:54
10:53:12 INFO: Samples count: 1202, 2.08% failures
10:53:12 INFO: Average times: total 26.906, latency 0.132, connect 0.233
10:53:12 INFO: Percentiles:
┌───────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Percentile, % │ Resp. Time, s │
├───────────────┼───────────────┤
│           0.0 │         0.728 │
│          50.0 │        23.631 │
│          90.0 │        43.903 │
│          95.0 │        56.927 │
│          99.0 │        84.351 │
│          99.9 │       104.895 │
│         100.0 │       125.503 │
└───────────────┴───────────────┘
10:53:12 INFO: Request label stats:
┌─────────────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬───────────────────┐
│ label           │ status │   succ │ avg_rt │ error             │
├─────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼───────────────────┤
│ http://websi.te │  FAIL  │ 97.92% │ 26.906 │ Moved Permanently │
└─────────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴───────────────────┘
```

For example:

1. `Resp. Time, s: 43.903` - does this mean that my website responded in 40% of the cases after 40 seconds? This would be impossible, because it responses after 1-2 seconds if I visit it via a web browser.
2. Is `avg_rt` (average response time?) about 26 seconds? Impossible.

If I look at the Chromium Performance test, most elemets (Network, Frames, Scripts) are done after 1000ms the network waterfall is done after about 650ms.

I have also tested `linguee.com` with Taurus and it gives me similar figures:

- avg_rt: 15 seconds
- 50%: 10 seconds
- 90%: 24 seconds
- 95%: 56 seconds

Is there a misconception? How is it even possible, that 90% of all requests had a response time of 24 seconds? check it by yourself and go to linguee.com, it about 2000ms.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

My config file looks as follows

```
execution:
- concurrency: 100
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 5m
  scenario: quick-test

scenarios:
  quick-test:
    requests:
    - https://www.linguee.com
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `Resp. Time, s 43.903` for [90% percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) means that response time was at least 43 seconds for **90% of requests**
2. `avg_rt` stands for average response time. It is [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of **all** samplers duration divided by their count. In your case it's 26 seconds

With regards to your "impossible" statements:

- Your test assumes 1202 request
- Your test duration is 7 minutes

It means that each minute you fired 171 request which gives ~2.85 requests per second. I wouldn't state that looks like a "load test" to me, most probably your system performance is a big question mark. You can try opening your [system under test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) in browser **while your test is running** and prepare to be surprised.

So I would start investigating why your system responds so slowly and first of all checked whether it has enough resources (RAM, CPU, Network, Disk. etc.), you can do this using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have edited my question.

Comment: How does your YAML config file look like?

Comment: I can see 2 possible issues: 1. Your machine simply cannot simulate 100 concurrent users.  Keep an eye on CPU and RAM usage while Taurus is running. 2. There are DDoS protection mechanisms (at least for linguee.com) which prevents you from load testing. If you need some host to play with you can try http://blazedemo.com

Comment: Just tried blazedemo.com, my CPU was behaving normal but the result is even more strange than on other hosts: Samples count: 4383886, 100.00% failures, avg_rt 00.000

Answer (score 0):

There are following possibilities for your bad results if you're really testing external website like linguee:

- Your network card cannot handle the underlying traffic, so you're not testing the website but your network
- The target website has DDOS protection mechanism and slows down your requests
- Your machine is overloaded

Regarding blazedemo, it seems the website is down or facing performance issues.

Note you should never do load test on a website you don't own as it is considered as a DDOS attack